# Fixed header popping, only in safari only on blog pages

Tags: header, safari, fixed

The header works fine in all browsers and on all pages EXCEPT for the blog pages in safari. On these pages the header disappears when you scroll down the page and then reappears at the bottom. The links in the header can still be clicked on when it is hidden though.

I've tried playing around the z-index but with no luck

```
#header{ padding: 31px 0 0;
position:fixed;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
z-index:10000;
top: 0; 
left: 0;
opacity: .95;
 }

#precontent { 
overflow:hidden;
padding-top:100px;

}
}
```

Homepage - with no issues

http://bit.ly/HTACng

Blog - page with disappearing/reappearing header on scroll down

http://bit.ly/12kq6MM

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated as I'm really stuck on why this is only occurring in safari.